# How to check IF several files exist in a folder with foreach activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory

UPDATE

I am uploading 2 files (and each will have same filename every week) in an Azure Blob storage container.

I would like to execute another pipeline only if these two files exist.

So what I thought to do is :

1. Create an empty folder in an Azure blob storage container
2. Upload these two files in this folder
3. Check in this folder if they exist to execute a main pipeline. Two triggers for each file, and I guess with the second trigger I will find both files.
   a) Get metadata activity
   b) Foreach activity
   c) If condition : to check if the two specific files exist
4. If they exist I move these two files to another folder and execute the other pipeline. This way I keep the folder empty for next upload.

These two files will always have the same name. Example: file_1.csv and file_2.csv

[image]

But I don't know if it is technically possible and what to do inside of each these steps, what can I do ?

Comment: Why use GMD when you have a trigger? Or did you mean something else by trigger?

Comment: Because I want to trigger my main pipeline only if when these two files exist (i.e. if they have been added). I will update my post, I agree with you, not clear about trigger

Comment: ok so I provided how to do it in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to check if file exists and the name name of the files, The `Get Metadata activity` will return the values for the `Arguments` you have added in `Field list`.

[image]

For example, it has return below output for `Exists` and `Child items` Arguments.

[image]

Now, in the Foreach activity only, you can capture the `Child items` values by using dynamic expression in `Foreach activity` -> `Settings` tab `Item` field.

Use below expression:

`@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`

Use the `IF Condition activity` in `ForEach activity` rather than separately. And based on the child field names you can further assign the task in True and False conditions inside `IF Condition activity`.

Comment: Hi, thank you I'm trying your advices. Do I have to check "Sequential" in ForEach settings ? I don't understand where to put the real file names in the If Condition, is it dynamic content or something else ?

Comment: what is your actual requirement? do you need to check file names or just need to check if file exists? please provide some details about use case.

Comment: My goal is to execute another pipeline only if two precise files exist, I know the filename for these two files. I am updating my post above too.

Comment: please refer this once and let me know if it's helpful - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6246/azure-data-factory-get-metadata-example/

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading it. My question is updated too

Comment: Thank you. If the referred link would be helpful, I would update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry I tried to apply the referred link but don't understand how to use it to find if my two files exist

Comment: I think I can compare an array of filename because all the filename will always be same ['file_1', 'file_2'] to have with array of filename existing in  the folder. But don't know where to put the array of filename to have

Comment: Hey jos97!, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Comment: Hello thank you it solved the problem ! :)

Answer (score 1):

So this is how I would roll it. The architecture is adaptation of binary AND, i.e. when A AND B are both true then do something. Now since each A and B are independent events and one can happen before other we need to wait for the other event before executing the process.

So here are two approaches:

**#1**

- you only have trigger on file_2.csv which triggers the ADF pipeline.
- in ADF start with UNTIL activity ; inside this run a wait activity for say  a minute and then run GMD to grab child items and then run filter activity to check if the file_1.csv is present in the child items array. if yes then set a variable which breaks until condition
- write your processing logic as now both files are available

This approach is good if we know both files will arrive within some duration of one another. However I would bake in a logic to break out and end pipeline in error when say 20 min have passed without second file arriving.

#2

- you can pass with blob event trigger the name of file. See [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables#storage-event-trigger-scope) on how it is done with `@triggerBody().fileName`. So have a trigger on both files.
- next thing I will move this file to a new folder. But before I do, I will check count of files which already exist in the destination folder. If it's 0 then my new file will have have prefix of file1- added to it. file1-originalfilename. If the destination already has 1 file, then  prefix is file2-.
- have a trigger on destination folder which trigger if a file with a prefix of file2-. in this new triggered pipeline write your processing code.